# AngularJS ng-repeat with limitTo

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to type:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:what">
```

where I can substitute "what" with something that will make it iterate through the whole list of items. (note **items.length** is not what I am searching for.. or it must be with some ugly if inside the html).

Comment: Why does `items.length` not work?

Comment: it works as supposed to, its just I will have to write some ng-ifs or something of this kind right? (if what is not a number then..) I was hoping there is another way

Comment: confused by the question. "make it iterate through the whole list of items". Does not the construct `ng-repeat="item in items"` do that by default? - Wait - Are you saying the `what` value is meant to be dynamic(change in value) bound to select list for example?

Comment: yep :) you got it.. the point is that I had directive inside directive with ng-repeats that I determined how many times to cycle through logic in the controller and it is obviously bad design and could do something better.. still I hoped there was a way to do it

Comment: thx for making clear

Comment: I can always put $scope.what = 1291273193211231 or kind of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/limitTo.js#L3) for `limitTo` there is support for an infinite number (`Infinity`):

```
    if (Math.abs(Number(limit)) === Infinity) {
      limit = Number(limit);
    } else {
      limit = int(limit);
    }
```

Looks like you should be able to set to `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

However, the resulting code would probably be no better than using `items.length`.  And would certainly be less understandable.

Comment: Thank you sir, you understood exactly what I was asking for. And that answer pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `{{  }}`, here is the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:what">
```

in the controller

```
$scope.what = 3; // iterate only 3
```

Comment: okay 10x, I will edit my question :)

But yet:
- can I make something like $scope.what = 'infinitive';
so to iterate through all items

Answer (score 0):

This is simple man

```
<div ng-repeat ="item in items | limitTo:10">

or $scope.what = '10'; and use what in limit.
```